# how can i load BitmapEx.h

Tags: c++

I am working on MFC with c++. i got this error:

```
Cannot open include file: 'BitmapEx.h': No such file or directory.
```

plzz tell me how can i include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this file? Is it on your disk?

If it is not one of the standard includes, you should put it in your CPP directory and include with double quotes, `#include "BitmapEx.h"`

Comment: i copied this code and get the above described error. i dont know that it exist or not. how can i check that it exist in my directory or not?
#include "BitmapEx.h"
CBitmapEx bitmapEx;
bitmapEx.Load(_T("Enter bitmap source file path here..."));
bitmapEx.Rotate(45);
bitmapEx.Sepia();
bitmapEx.Scale(50, 50);
bitmapEx.Draw(hDC);
bitmapEx.Save(_T("Enter bitmap destination file path here..."));

Comment: i am working on visual stdio and making an image analyser as my project.

Comment: Where have you copied it from? This doesn't look like MFC code to me. BitmapEx looks like a 3rd-party library, which has to be downloaded.

Comment: i copied it from here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/CBitmapEx.aspx
i think u r rite. i just want to increase/decrease the brightness of a bitmap, thats why i m using BitmapEx.h. is there any other way? please help.............

Comment: The link you pointed lets you download this include file, doesn't it?

Comment: i think yes. i have downloaded it. where should i extraxt it? i wanna know that where the files r placed which we include in our projects like "resource.h" etc?

Comment: you should instruct it near your CPP files, and add it to your project. It is going to be a part of your source code.

Comment: finally i will able to add the header file by ur and david's help. thank u soooo much :) but plz resolve this error 
error C2065: 'hDC' : undeclared identifier

Comment: where r u Pavel? i need ur help. plzz explain what is 3rd party library for my viva

Comment: hDC? Where? Let's continue in a separate question about the device context handle..

Comment: the code i copied gives this error. yes i have started it as a separate question. plz explain what is meant by 3rd party library for my viva

Comment: 3rd party include = not yours and not visual studio's. Please point me to the question ID..

Comment: sorry i didnt find question's ID. take this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118495/how-can-i-declare-hdc

Answer (score 0):

Does the file exist?

If it does you need to add its path to the additional include directories for your project.

You could try giving it an absolute path, but using the include directories would be better

If the file does not exist, for example if it is part of a [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/89380/a-question-about-BitmapEx-h.aspx), then you need to be sure you have downloaded the file, and put it in the same folder as the file that includes it.

If it is part of the [Codeproject CBitmapEx - Free C++ Bitmap Manipulation Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/CBitmapEx.aspx) then you will need to log on there to download it

Comment: if it does not exist, from where i can get this file?

Comment: i am working on visual stdio and making an image analyser as my project.